# Django TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I get an error when creating a new user via a form on the site, or via `python manage.py createsuperuser`: `TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'force_insert'`

signals.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

I tried passing `args, **kwargs` to get `def save(self, *args, **kwargs)` and `super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`.

I also tried passing these arguments to `signals.py`. The error remains, I don't know what to do. If you need more code from any script, I will provide it all

Read other threads on this topic, but the solution didn't work for me